# Change Label Text Based on SQL query result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I would like to set the label that I have as projPoints1 to epual what the SQL query returns.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
using (QC.SqlCommand cmd = new QC.SqlCommand("SELECT *,[proj] FROM[dbo].[WeeklyStats] WHERE[playerID] = @player1 AND [weeks] = @week1 "))
{
    string week1 = Weeks.SelectedValue.ToString();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player1", playerArr[0].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week1", week1);

    //runs the sql statement and adds them all to the dropdown list
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandType = DT.CommandType.Text;

    QC.SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    projPoints1.Text = ;
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think their is nothing wrong with accessing the value from the reader, You can use something like this :

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   projPoints1.Text = reader["proj"].ToString();
}
```

If you need only the `proj` then you can modify the query by removing the `*` Something like this: `SELECT [proj] FROM[dbo].[WeeklyStats] ...` this time you can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` to get the value; code for that will be :

```
 projPoints1.Text = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```